# Powershell Application - Master and Client model

Tags: powershell

I have a script which collect systems inventory. I want to convert this script as application to connect all my network servers and pull the information.

Q1 . How to deploy the script to remote machine

Q2 . How to update the code if changes made.

Q3 . How to control everything in One server (Manage all remote server from one server and update the code if any changes to collect inventory)

Q4. Any application written in powershell which has similar process master and client.

I have tried to convert the script to exe and copy over network and run locally.

```
Function Invent
{
param($servers)

foreach ($server in $servers) 
{

       $output = [ordered]@{

            'ServerName'         = $server
            'OperatingSystem'    = (Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $server -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption
            'FreeDiskSpace (GB)' = [Math]::Round(((Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $server -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk | Measure-Object -Property FreeSpace -Sum).Sum / 1GB),1)
            'Memory (GB)'        = (Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $server -ClassName Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property Capacity -Sum).Sum /1GB

        }

        [pscustomobject]$output | out-file .\$server.txt
    }}
```

how to make this script to run as master server and deploy script to remote machine? if any code update how to update for remote machine? if install as service how to update the code for the service?

Mainly the script should run on remote machine resources. only the trigger point in single server

Comment: You've asked an awful lot of questions here, each of which is pretty broad by itself.  I'm not clear on why you'd want to introduce the complexity of running and maintaining this code on each client when you can just query this information from the "master" server like you're already doing.  Unless there's more to your script than the simple function you've shown here, there's nothing here that requires client-side processing, so why do you want to do that?  Is there a huge number of servers to be inventoried?  Multiple sites with not-necessarily-fast connections?  Security limitations?

Comment: What do you mean with update the script when changes are made? Usually a change is an update in itself. Can you please specify what is your problem (error)? Besides, function names always have a Verb-Noun name. It never should be just a noun.

Comment: @BACON I have to run a script to weekly around 1k+ servers so I don’t want to use “master “ server resources . If it’s running on individual servers the runtime will be faster. The example show here is sample actual script would run 10mins approx(tested) locally. The code will be change if required.how to do that? We have security limitations as well no PSremoting enabled and 6 doamins.

Comment: @Alex_P the problem is “need to run script in to remote server and use its resources” the script will be changed when required.

Comment: Anyone can help on this?